# Reset position of HTML element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, positioning

I am changing the absolute position of an Image element with Javascript by adding following CSS class via classList.add(".moving"):

```
.moving {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

When a certain event occurs, I would like that img to go back in its previous (standard flow) place inside a div container. I've already removed the .moving class and also set the position and display properties back to relative and inline manually.

```
pic.classList.remove(".moving");
puzzleSource.style = "position: relative; display: inline";
```

Somehow I can't wrap my head around this. Hope one of you guys can help me out.

Comment: Take the dot (.) out of the parameter you are giving the remove function.

Comment: OK, so what is the trigger event?

Comment: classList.add and remove must not have the dot

Answer (score 0):

I feel so dumb now - I formatted the div container

```
puzzleSource.style = "position: relative; display: inline";
```

instead of the pic.

Sorry for bothering! It works now.